# Azure scaling with Orchard cms

Tags: azure, orchardcms

I was reading through these questions:

[Scaling Orchard with Azure Web Sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582947/scaling-orchard-with-azure-web-sites)

[Orchard CMS Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100193/orchard-cms-performance)

[How to deploy Orchard CMS in Windows Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442141/how-to-deploy-orchard-cms-in-windows-azure)

I started to think about an e-commerce project I am undertaking and would like to clarify a few things if possible.

**Please forgive me because I am finding it very difficult to articulate this question in a way I feel I have clearly communicated what I am thinking.**

Firstly, what factors and when would those factors kick in for me to start thinking about scaling to handle the traffic of my web site. The type of factors I am aware of would include:

1. Session handling
2. Caching
3. I am thinking the amount of data being served in a request but not sure on the full implications of request size

Secondly, with all things there should be a certain level of up-front planning when trying to set up a web site that can handle traffic of certain levels. Would the Azure scaling need to be done upfront or is it a simple matter to make it work now for what is needed and then up-scale at a later date when it is necessary?

Let me give a real life scenario to try aid where my fear is:

> *A radio broadcast was put out for a certain web site trying to sell
>   their wares. The web site was not planned very well. The web site
>   started to receive visits from people listening to the radio show. So
>   many visitors that the web site was not able to handle the traffic and
>   an error message was displayed telling the world that they should
>   'talk to the administrator' or words to that effect. You know the
>   picture I am sure and I am also very certain it would be embarrassing
>   for any web developer to be told that this was happening to a web site
>   they had designed.*

I would really like to really be able to distil a proper question out of this, but there are many things that I am just not aware of. To try an make this question less vague I will try to summarise what I would like to achieve:

I want to have a web site that is able to handle a lot of traffic following successful advertising/marketing campaigns. I want to walk the tightrope of budget versus functionality, which is why I would like to be able to do the least amount possible to start with and be able to ***easily*** up-scale as demand dictates.

Bearing this in mind, what approach/considerations should I take to avoid nasty pitfalls with performance/availability/reliability when using an Orchard CMS/Azure combination to deliver my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orchard on Azure Web Sites is working great for us, see http://nublr.pt

A few things to bear in mind with the site configuration are:

- follow the guidelines in http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Optimizing-Performance-of-Orchard-with-Shared-Hosting
- set up caching (module Contrib.Cache available in the gallery) which will use IIS's application cache.
- set up the Warmup feature to keep the site alive,
- also ensure that dynamic compilation is off by using the Config/HostComponents.config

We are currently in "shared" mode of azure web sites, we don't have much traffic yet, but out load testing with https://loadimpact.com has not taken the site down once. at any time we can move to the "reserved" mode (it does take up to 24h for it to happen)

Version 1.6 will bring a lot of improvements to Orchard, try to get started with your development in it.

Hope this has helped.

Comment: oh i forgot to mention, we do use https://www.cloudflare.com/ free version, that does help a lot!

Comment: Thanks for your response, I don't suppose you have been in the situation where you needed to up scale your site to cope with a massive increase in traffic. If you did how would the caching be handled? Is there anything to be aware of with regard to caching, I do not want anything coming left field and catching me off guard.

Comment: caching is being handled by cloudflare and the module, I have not upscalled yet, but I assume the module cache's will have to be redone, if the rebuild of orchard takes some time, you could have some downtime. if uptime is critical (e.g. 100%) you should probably consider another route, that I know of web farming with web sites is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the information it goes some way to give me an idea of what I need to know, I will leave the question available for a while but if I get no more responses I will mark yours as the answer. Thanks again for taking the time to provide some insight.